# S3 buckets are not listed in Jenkins Active choice parameter Plugin

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, groovy, jenkins-plugins

Hi Guys I'm trying to list only files names in a specific bucket in my s3 , and I got suceeded with the following command in aws cli,

```
aws s3 ls s3://inc-eb-deployments/my-bucket/ | awk '{ print $4 }'
```

But I want to add this AWS cli command in to my groovy script in Jenkins "Active Choice Parameter" Plugin, I've added it like below,

```
def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()
def proc = 'aws s3 ls s3://inc-eb-deployments/my-bucket/ | awk '{ print $4 }' '.execute()
proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(2000)
def values = "$sout".split('.zip')
def trimmedValues
def parameters=[]
values.each {  println "${it}" }
def cleanValues = "$sout".split('inc')
def last = cleanValues.last().split('.zip')[0]
cleanValues.each {  "${it}".toString(); 
                    trimmedValues = "${it}".trim();
                    parameters<<trimmedValues
                 }
parameters.remove(parameters.size() - 1);
parameters.add(last)
parameters
```

But When I run the Job I don't see any filename outputs on the build page.

[image]

Anyone can help me where's the issue in this Groovy script ?

Answer (score 1):

This can not work, as String.execute() does "stupid things" (it splits on whitespace) and execute at all does not run a shell at all - it just `exec`s. If you want to use shellism in the groovy world use:

```
def proc = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "aws s3 ls s3://inc-eb-deployments/my-bucket/ | awk '{ print \$4 }' "].execute()
```

Comment: Your answer was a good initiative and Thanks for it, but there were some syntax errors and I changed it in the answer.

Comment: The original code had one closing `'` to much (so the shell code would have given an error). I assume, that jenkins did not like the triple `'` - it works with groovy 3 though.

Answer (score 0):

```
def proc = ["/bin/sh", "-c", "aws s3 ls s3://inc-eb-deployments/my-bucket/ | awk '{ print \$4 }' "].execute()
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code:

```
def s3_path = "s3://bucket/path/to/files/"
def aws_s3_ls_output = "aws s3 ls ${s3_path} --region us-east-1".execute() \
                       | ['awk', '{ print $NF }'].execute()
//aws_s3_ls_output.waitFor() // might be needed if execution is too long
def files = aws_s3_ls_output.text.tokenize().reverse()

return files
```

[image]